# need to fetch A1 and A2 with minimum FirstTime and LastTime within all X1, X2 and X3. Looking for better way?

Tags: c#

I have below data model, against each X1, X2 and X3 I have A1 and A2 with either identical  FirstTime and LastTime or with different values.

```
var dataModel = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, DataModel>>
        {
            {
                "X1",
                new Dictionary<string, DataModel>
                {
                        {
                            "A1",
                            new DataModel { Name="A1", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        },
                        {
                            "A2",
                            new DataModel { Name="A2", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        }
                }
            },

            {
                "X2",
                new Dictionary<string, DataModel>
                {
                        {
                            "A1",
                            new DataModel { Name="A1", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 11, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        },
                        {
                            "A2",
                            new DataModel { Name="A2", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 11, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 11, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        }
                }
            },
            {
                "X3",
                new Dictionary<string, DataModel>
                {
                        {
                            "A1",
                            new DataModel { Name="A1", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        },
                        {
                            "A2",
                            new DataModel { Name="A2", FirstTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 15, 5, 30, 45), LastTime = new DateTime(2020, 12, 16, 5, 30, 45) }
                        }
                }
            }
        };
```

I need to fetch A1 and A2 with minimum FirstTime and LastTime within all X1, X2 and X3. Here is my try, Is there other better way?

```
 var lstDataModel = new List<DataModel>();

        foreach (var dm in dataModel)
        {
            foreach (var val in dm.Value)
            {
                lstDataModel.Add(new DataModel
                {
                    Name = val.Value.Name,
                    FirstTime = val.Value.FirstTime,
                    LastTime = val.Value.LastTime,
                });
               
            }
        }

        var query = lstDataModel
                      .GroupBy(cm => cm.Name)
                      .Select(g => new {
                          g.Key,
                          FirstTime = g.Min(cm => cm.FirstTime),
                          LastTime = g.Min(cm => cm.LastTime)
                      }).ToList();
```

Here is `DataModel` class,

```
public class DataModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime FirstTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If this way is good enough then you don't need a better way. Is this way good enough for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming they all have the same keys (A1/A2):

```cs
var query = dataModel.Values
    .SelectMany(d => d.Keys)
    .Distinct()
    .Select(key => new
    {
        Key = key,
        FirstTime = dataModel.Values.Min(v => v[key].FirstTime),
        LastTime = dataModel.Values.Min(v => v[key].LastTime),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Not sure if it's 'better' but it takes fewer lines of code

Comment: Thanks for assuming that  keys (A1/A2) are same . Yes it is. and this fewer line of code works like charm.